# java linkedlist find method

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I am having difficulty on my Java lab assignment.

Here are my codes and the instruction:

If the key is not there, it should
   return the PREVIOUS Node.  If there is not previous (key==Aaron),
   return null.

```
 protected Node<K, V> find (K key, Node start) {
  for (Node<K, V> node = start == null ? head : (Node<K, V>) start;
  node != null; node = node.next){
    if(key.equals(node.key)){
        return node;
    }
    else if(!key.equals(node.key)){
        node=node.next;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
  }
  return tail;
}
```

C E G I K M O Q S U W Y

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24

Here is the linkedlist.

My output is 
C E G I K M O Q S U W Y 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24

containsKey(A) = false

containsKey(C) = true

containsKey(L) = false

containsKey(M) = false

containsKey(Y) = true

containsKey(Z) = false

but for M, it should also return true 
how do I fix this problem?

Comment: I am missing how all this is connected.  Since you've tagged doubly-linked-list, I assume Node has a previous field.  Is that true?  How do you get your output?  What does containsKey do?  Is this a method you wrote?  What is calling containsKey?

Answer (score 0):

you can work on this by using double Linked List or (which means that you have to change in the node class ) 
the other one is to have to node when points to the head and the other one behind the head ,

```
node p = null ; 
node q = head ;
```

every time you loop 
you will make

```
 p = q and q = q.next();
```

so , this way if you don't find the key you will return the p 
if you find it you will return q .